# Telegram: don't search my bot to start conversation

Tags: bots, telegram

I create a bot with BotFather.

What is the way to disable research bot? I don't want other users start a conversation with my bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a [whitelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) from Telegram IDs (include your own account Id) and ignore another updates.

Telegram users uniq ID are receive with each update and you can find it in this path:

```
update.chat.id
```

I think there is no other way.